# How to check if user is in a certain table

Tags: python, django

I have my user table in django, and to differ all the users I created two tables, (Teacher and Student).

Both tables are getting an fk from user

So, in order to make authorization how do I check if one's user is in a certain table.

I need to check it this way

```
def test_func(self):
    return self.request.user.check..if..it..exists..in..table
```

My models are like this.

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
   User = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on how your models are set up.

If your Teacher model looks something like this;

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Then you should be able to check if the user is a teacher by using the implicit backref;

```
self.request.user.teacher_set.exists()
```

---

As the question has been updated to show that the model is slightly different than I anticipated, here is an update.

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

Which means that the backref will be a little different.

```
hasattr(self.request.user, "teacher")
```

As you've mentioned that you are doing this inside a django template, I'm pretty sure that the following will work:

```
{% if user.teacher %}
```

Comment: Good answer, How would it be in html ? I tried {% if user.teacher_set.exists() %} but I get an operator expected.

Comment: Out of interest - try just dropping the brackets?

Comment: Thank you for such an answer.

Comment: Glad to help :) Next time you ask a question, remember to include all useful details.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't posted your models, I am giving you a rough idea how to do it.

in your **views.py** -

```
from .models import Teacher,Student

def test_func(request):
    user = request.user
    if (Teacher.objects.filter(user=user).count() > 0) or (Student.objects.filter(user=user).count > 0):
        #do your stuffs here..
```

Comment: You should use `exists()` instead of count. There is no point going to the effort to count people when all you care about is whether they exist at all.

Comment: Yes, I agree.. Your answer is better

Answer (score 1):

One way is to query both tables:

```
teacher = Teacher.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
student = Student.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
if teacher or student:
     # do what you want.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put in your relation the argument "related_name" you can do it using inverse relationship

```
class SomeTable(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, #Your user model or Django one
        verbose_name = "User",
        related_name = "inverse_relation_name"
    )
```

Then you have to call using keyword arguments for the filters:

```
SomeTable.inverse_relation_name.filter(id=self.request.user.id) #You will get a queryset
```

Or

```
SomeTable.inverse_relation_name.get(id=self.request.user.id) # You will get the object or a exception
```

Comment: You'll get a queryset - not a list. Also your queries don't look right to me - you seem to be looking up a record in SomeTable using the pk of the user... If this actually works it'll be coincidence...

Comment: You're right, it's a queryset, the filter case won't throw an exception if there is no coincidence, but it's only one line of code

Comment: The coincidence part was about you looking up a model by the id of a different unrelated model...

Comment: I've seen my mistake, I haven't seen that Goun2 was using OneToOne , that does not have the related_name property, it have the related table in the object if exists